# Alterar cor do site com jquery

Tags: jquery

Existe alguma forma de alterar a cor de todo o site com jquery?
tipo, eu tenho um site que a cor padrão dele é roxo, mas só algumas partes, e eu queria alterar essas partes de acordo com a escolha do usuário, eu queria um jeito que o js não alterasse o código fonte no console...

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: "_eu queria um jeito que o js não alterasse o código fonte no console_"... como assim? Seria impedir alterações via console?

Comment: Com "CSS Variable" vc consegui isso de maneira bem fácil até. Mas sua pergunta é muito ampla é difícil de te responder assim, Crie um exemplo com código e edite sua pergunta que fica mais fácil

Comment: @hugocsl Ampla mesmo, porque se der um F5 volta tudo ao normal.

Comment: Se vcs olharem o twitter, na parte de alterar o tema, ele vai mudar a cor de todo o site, mas se olharem o codigo fonte no console, vão ver que nada é alterado, parece magica, mas não descobri como

Comment: @dvd e ai vai cookie / localStorage etc... difícil de dar uma resposta simples... Roberto, comece com perguntas mais claras e objetivas, conforme seu projeto for andando vc vai perguntando novamente que o site é pra isso mesmo.

Comment: Robert, mas veja que isso é bem desnecessário o fato de ter no console ou não as alterações. O que importa é o que o usuário vê na tela

Comment: Descobri como ... é bem complexo msm, mas assim que eu terminar, vou postar o codigo

Comment: Vinculado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/como-se-memoriza-uma-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-site

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o js não alterar o código fonte no console eu não posso lhe ajudar, mas sobre mudar a cor com jquery é só atribuir uma class igual a todos elementos que você queira que mude de cor e fazer isso:

```
//class do botão que muda de cor
$('.btn-muda-cor').click( function(){
    //aqui eu pego o id, cada id vc pode colocar algo para identificar a cor 
    //que você deseja atribuir, ex: o id que eu peguei é igual a 1,então eu 
    //faço um if na hora de atribuir a cor que se id = 1 cor seja vermelha 
    //por exemplo.
    var id_campo = this.id;

    //chamo a função para atribuir a cor passando o id do campo
    atribuir_cor(id_campo);
});

function atribuir_cor(id){
    //comparo o id
    if(id == 1){
        //aí você coloca a class que quer que mude de cor
        $('.class').css('background', red);
        //o .css recebe 2 parâmeotros, o primeiro é o o nome da instrução do 
        //css e a segunda o valor que será atribuido a ele
    }
}
```

Sobre dar f5 e reiniciar, dá pra gravar a cor ou salvar a variavel em como de sessão em php, assim você mantem a cor quando mudar de página, der f5 etc. Ou se seu site tiver clientes cadastrados, vc pode salvar num db, aí quando logar o site vai pra cor que ele definiu anteriormente

Comment: Vários elementos com o mesmo `id`?

Comment: @dvd com o msm class, eu coloquei msm id? Se foi perdão, confundi aqui kkkkkk