# Como se "memoriza" uma ação em um site?

Tags: css

Estou querendo colocar no meu blog, a possibilidade de trocar o tema dele (background/color), por CSS e JavaScript. Porém adoraria que fosse possível "memorizar" esta ação, para que sempre que o usuário voltar a entrar, o tema esteja no último que ele escolheu (até que de alguma forma ela limpe estes dados, claro).
Não entendo essa coisa mas imagino ser bem complexa. Podem me explicar brevemente como funciona? E se não for tão complexo assim, podem me dizer o que fazer?

Comment: Você poderia lançar para o servidor guardar qual foi o estilo que o usuário preferiu, resultando então que ele acessaria do jeito favorito em qualquer navegador... ou você poderia salvar a escolha como um cookie ou coisa que o valha (armazenamento SQLite se não me engano é possível) usando JS. Essa segunda alternativa só manteria a preferência do usuário no navegador em que foi feita essa escolha, entretanto. E para consumir corretamente o site seria necessário ter um script que trataria esses cookies para enviar os arquivos adequados

Comment: Essa segunda opção é mais apropriada, já que não tenho sistema de login lá. Vou dar uma pesquisada a mais sobre essa sua dica

Comment: boa pesquisa. Não se esqueça de, caso consiga encontrar a resposta adequada, postá-la aqui. Eu entendo a teoria do que se deveria fazer, mas não faço a mínima ideia do como fazer. Respondendo aqui você ajudaria a todos nós, inclusive a si mesmo

Comment: ok, vou fazer isso!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tentei muuuuito que já estou exausta... Na internet achei demonstrações que funcionaram perfeitamente, mas são diferentes da forma que eu queria/preciso e não consegui relacionar com a lógica deles pra fazer o meu funcionar. Uma das que funcionou faz uma cintilação do estilo original por uns segundos antes de alterar (horrível), outra funciona muito bem mas não deixa ter um background padrão (qual a lógica?!). Outro é perfeito mas o usuário teria que digitar a cor que quer por um input, não dá pra ser assim..

Comment: Enfim... se tiver alguma dica ainda eu vou agradecer. E também posso te mandar de alguma forma os links das demos, se quiser dae uma olhada. Agora acho que vou postar um deles aqui no SO pra ver se alguem sabe resover.

Comment: Meu conhecimento infelizmente me limitou aos meus comentários prévios. Fico triste que sua busca não foi frutífera o suficiente =( Pensei que as duas respostas poderiam ter te ajudado... ou talvez a ajuda tenha vindo e não tenha percebido. Acontece, é frustrante, mas fazer o quê? Eu, bacharel em ciência da computação já fazem uns 5 anos, precisei ainda ficar observando e lendo e perguntando sobre programação funcional para começar a entender um pouco que seja </desabafo> Enfim, quando tiver 20 pontos de reputação poderá [falar no chat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) [...]

Comment: [...] Lá você poderá bater um papo cabeça com o pessoal, inclusive pessoas mais bem treinadas na parte web. Só peço para ter paciência e continuar estudando e colaborando =) As vezes as respostas demoram para vir, as vezes a gente demora para entender também. Não deixe que um tropeço te impeça de ir em frente

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) (HTML5):

Exemplo:

```js
// Guardar
localStorage.setItem("cor_css", "vermelho");
// Obter (aí você precisa moldar esta info recebida e aplicar nos objetos que você deseja
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("cor_css");
```

Comment: Nossa, só agora vi essa resposta. Ali em "cor_css" seria o nome da minha função com o conjunto dos estilos?

Comment: @KenyaJJ cor_css é um item que retém um valor. Eu coloquei "vermelho" mas pode ser um conjunto de informações no seu caso ;)

Answer (score 1):

Imaginando que você disponibiliza temas distintos para o usuário "customizar/escolher" aplicar estilos diferentes na UI do seu site, podes usar `localStorage()` ou cookies, ambas as soluções usam `javascript` e podem ser modificadas ou apagadas pelo usuário no front-end seja usando o console ou ferramentas do desenvolvedor, seja usando plugins ou mesmo indo a configurações e limpando os dados nas configurações do navegador ou mesmo você pode criar uma função para "limpar" estas configurações.

Exemplo usando `localStorage()`:

```
<!-- IN HEAD -->
<link id="css-template-link" rel="stylesheet" href="default-template.css">

<!-- IN BODY -->
<select id="select-css-template">
   <option value="default">Dedault Template</option>
   <option value="dark">Dark Template</option>
   <option value="cyan">Cyan Template</option>
   <option value="ice">Ice Template</option>
</select

<script>
    let select = document.getElementById('select-css-template')
    select.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
        let css = evt.options[evt.selectedIndex].value
        // apply
        let link = document.getElementById('css-template-link')
        link.href = css + '-template.css'
        // save to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('css-template', css)
    }, false)

    // load
    if ( localStorage.getItem('css-template') ) {
        let css = localStorage.getItem('css-template')
        let link = document.getElementById('css-template-link')
        // apply
        link.href = css + '-template.css'
    }

    // clear: localStorage.removeItem('css-template')
</script>
```

Usando `localStorage()` não existe por padrão nenhum tempo de expiração. Já uma bordagem com cookies necessita definir um tempo para expiração, uma função para buscar uma única entrada nos valores armazenados em `document.cookie` assim como uma função para rescrever os valores de um cookie (e também seu tempo de expiração) bem como para limpar (definir um tempo negativo).

Exemplo usando `document.cookie`

```
<script>
    // request cookie approach
    let getCookie = name => {
        return document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + name.replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1") || false
    }
    // save cookie
    let saveToCookie = (name, value, expirationDays) => {
        let makeTime = t => {
            if ( typeof t === 'number' ) {
                let d = new Date()
                d.setMilliseconds(d.getMilliseconds() + t * 864e+5) // 864e+5 equal 1 day or 86400000 milliseconds
                return d.toString()
            }
        }
        document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires= + makeTime(expirationDays) + '; path=/'
    }

    let select = document.getElementById('select-css-template')
    select.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
        let css = evt.options[evt.selectedIndex].value
        // apply
        let link = document.getElementById('css-template-link')
        link.href = css + '-template.css'
        // save in cookie
        saveToCookie('css-template', css, 30) // 30 days of expiration
    }, false)

    // load
    if ( getCookie('css-template') ) {
        let css = getCookie('css-template')
        let link = document.getElementById('css-template-link')
        // apply
        link.href = getCookie('css-template') + '-template.css'
    }

    // clear: saveToCookie('css-template', '', -1)
</script>
```

Limpar o cookie não irá fazer mudar o css de volta ao padrão, más seguindo a lógica fica fácil redefinir o link para o css padrão.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela reposta, super bem explicada! Vou fazer umas tentativas e volto aqui para dizer se tive resultados e selecionar a resposta correta. =)

Comment: voltei... pois bem, tentei muuuuito e não consegui... Nesse teu exemplo eu não compreendi muito bem, mas li matérias e mais matérias pra ver se entendia. Nada. Na internet eu testei alguns exemplos que funcionaram perfeitamente, mas é longe do jeito que eu quero que funcione e no meu caso em particular, eu não consigo fazer funcionar tentando entender a lógica. Um deles dá uma cintilação do estilo original (variando de 1 até 5 segundos) quando a página é recarregada e fica muito chato... Já o segundo não permite já ter background no css, tem que está sem nada ou não funciona...

Comment: Qual exemplo? com cookie ou `localStorage` e o que exatamente não entendeu? Quando uma folha de estilo é carregada pela primeira vez sim, ela leva alguns segundos (dependendo da velocidade de conexão) para ser carregada más, depois disto ela é armazenada em cache e as próximas mudanças ocorrem praticamente sem percepção (pq já estão no cache). Se você deseja "pré-armazenar" folhas de estilo para não "sentir" este efeito, ai já é outro história teria de usar `Service Worker`